# Como identificar que a aplicação parou de funcionar?

Tags: android

Preciso salvar uns dados toda vez que a aplicação fecha, fiz isso dando um override no `onStop`, `onDestroy`, `onPause` e funciona, em condições normais, mais quando a app da `crash`, ele não executa nenhum desses `override` e consequentemente não salva os dados que preciso.

Teria como eu identificar que o app parou de funcionar (crashou)?

Comment: Acho difícil, porque no caso de crash, nenhum evento é disparado... uma solução seria fazer um save periódico, igual emails ou aplicativos como `Word`, daí quando carregar o App, é possível recuperar esses dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor forma é identificar os pontos mais sensíveis de crash no seu app e tratá-los com blocos try/catch, com isso você pode salvar dados nesses pontos.

```
try{
  // Executa código "sensível" a travamentos
} catch {
  // Salva os dados da aplicação
}
```

Adicionalmente, como já sugerido, faça saves periódicos, inclusive nos métodos onDestroy, onPause, etc., como você já tem feito.

Não existe um "listener" para crashes na SDK, então você vai ter que fazer esses tratamentos sempre que possível.

EDIT: Você pode tentar essa sugestão de criar um custom handler de exceções que deram nessa pergunta no StackOverflow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256595/how-to-have-a-callback-for-when-a-crash-occurred-while-using-crashlytics-sdk